# HelloWorld application executes twice

Tags: managed-c++

I have started a C++ class in school, and my first assignment is, naturally, HelloWorld. My code is as follows:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>

using namespace System;

int main(array<System::String ^> ^args)
{
    Console::WriteLine("Hello World");//print hello world
    system("PAUSE");//wait for button press
    return 0;
}
```

It works as expected, except after I 'press any key to continue', the prompt comes up again. The last lines of output in Visual Studio look as follows:

```
The thread 'Win32 Thread' (0x1664) has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 'Win32 Thread' (0x11f4) has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The program '[3032] HelloWorld.exe: Managed (v4.0.30319)' has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The program '[3032] HelloWorld.exe: Native' has exited with code 0 (0x0).
```

So, it appears it literally starts the application in 2 separate threads. Why would that happen? Thanks in advance.

Comment: @LuchianGrigore It's Managed C++ (I've updated the tag).

Comment: It looks like your program is somehow being executed in both a managed and non-managed environment, despite the fact that it clearly should be running as compiled .NET bytecode, not native code.

Comment: Try compiling it in debug mode only. If you try to run the compiled .exe it should run only once.

Comment: I have tried running it in both Debug and Release modes, with same exact results. Also, upon running it through the .exe via FAR manager, a new prompt came up, and then same prompt came up again in FAR. So, safe to say there were still 2 separate threads if running through the .exe.

Comment: It seems you don't need `#include<iostream>` unless you write using `std::cout`.

Comment: Also, `system("PAUSE")` is a awful way of making program waiting for pressing a key - it invokes `pause` program to do this. There are another ways to do that, I think the simplest is to `#include<conio.h> and use `getch()` instead.

Comment: Ginger, Ill keep that in mind. Right now my main issue is why does it start in 2 threads? My book and google search of various forums are not turning up any good results and I cant even find a comprehensive documentation of Visual Studio.

Comment: @user1219387: My speculation is that the "native" thread is part of the .Net framekwork, and the managed thread is your code.  Or maybe the other way around.  Either way, one of those threads is from the framework.

Answer (score 1):

Had the same problem today with a c# console application. Every time I executed the .exe file the window opened and after some time it would close and a new one popped up. After doing some research I found that I had to **disable the Avast Antivirus 'Deep Screen' feature**. It now runs properly.

Answer (score 0):

i hade same problem.

i resolved my issue with

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{

    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}
```

instead of ... return0; and after it, system("PAUSE");